# While waiting for a Swedish residency card I am not allowed to travel in the EU/Schengen zone

Tags: eu-spouses, sweden

Can I please get clarity why Swedish Immigration would not extend a residency permit while waiting for a residency card? Leaving one without any legal residency documentation for 15 months. I am an EU spouse and have no legal document (permit) to travel within the EU while waiting for the residency card. If I want to leave the country I can only re-enter after 2 months on a visa. How do I appeal this process?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "EU spouse" please?  Do you mean you are a citizen of a non-EU country, and are married to a citizen of a non-Swedish but EU country?  (So are you entitled to live in Sweden.)

Comment: There's always [SOLVIT](http://ec.europa.eu/solvit/).  If you truly are unable to travel within the EU for 15 months then you are not exactly "enjoying a right of freedom of movement."  If the linked duplicate does not answer your question, please edit your question to explain why.  Thanks, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Please check the possible-duplicate and edit your question to explain why this is a different issue (if it is different). Specifically, one of the answers says the process is required to conclude within 6 months, not 15.